# Initialize an ImmutableMap with explicit types?

Tags: java, guava

I need to initialize an ImmutableMap (guava 21.0) and I need it to resolve to a Map> for this example I will just use String.

So I have:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String,String> testMap = 
         ImmutableMap<String,String>.builder().put("a","b").build();
```

and on that last line I get a huge amount of compiler errors. The use of `ImmutableMap<String,String>.of()` gets the same result.

If I remove  I just get one error, a type mismatch.

How can I use ImmutableMap for explicit (literal-like) initialization when I do want a map with explicit types?

Answer (score 9):

Place generic types *after* the dot:

```
private Map<String, String> testMap = 
    ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().put("a","b").build();
```

See great [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ section on "What is explicit type argument specification?"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20explicit%20type%20argument%20specification?) for more details.

Comment: Coming from C# this is very difficult to remember, thanks @Xaerxess for helping me out of a pit of frustration!

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't need to use the builder, there's no need to specify generic type parameters either.

Just use:

```
Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of("a", "b");
```

Generic type parameters will be inferred by the compiler.

If, on the other hand, you need to use the builder, then the answer from @Xaerxess explains what you have to do.

Comment: True, but OP started with builder, which still requires explicit types and is needed for bigger maps (and for readability in such cases).

Comment: @Xaerxess You are absolutely correct. I upvoted your answer, which answers OP's question directly. My answer is intended to be a complement to yours. I will rewrite it to make this more clear.