# Java generic bi-function to return value based on specified class type

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to write generic Json deserializer as below,

```
  public static <T> BiFunction<String, Class<T>, T> jsonDeSerializer() {
    return (o, c) -> {
      try {
        return mapper.readValue(o, c);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("json.parse.error object.type={}", o.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        throw new JsonProcessingEx(e);
      }
    };
  }
```

When trying to call, I am getting

```
error: incompatible types: Class<MLAdhocResponseVO> cannot be converted to Class<Object>
    MLAdhocResponseVO response = JsonUtils.jsonDeSerializer().apply("{}", MLAdhocResponseVO.class);
```

All I want to to write a BiFunction which returns Object based on provided class without need of any typecasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
JsonUtils.jsonDeSerializer().apply("{}", MLAdhocResponseVO.class);
```

`jsonDeSerializer()`'s generic type argument is `Object` ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878008/generic-type-parameters-inference-in-method-chaining) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-does-not-compile-using-lambda/25173599#25173599) can shed more light), not `MLAdhocResponseVO` as you seem to expect.

The quick fix is to add a type witness to the call, to tell the compiler what your intended type argument for the method is:

```
MLAdhocResponseVO response = JsonUtils.<MLAdhocResponseVO>jsonDeSerializer()
        .apply("{}", MLAdhocResponseVO.class);
```

Alternatively, you can give the compiler a target type by declaring a typed `BiFunction` variable:

```
BiFunction<String, Class<MLAdhocResponseVO>, MLAdhocResponseVO> 
                        function = jsonDeSerializer();
MLAdhocResponseVO response = function.apply("{}", MLAdhocResponseVO.class);
```

---

If you want to avoid this altogether, then your method may be better designed with an actual parameter of the generic type, which will assist the compiler's type inference:

```
public static <T> Function<String, T> jsonDeSerializer(Class<T> c) {
    return (o) -> {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(o, c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("json.parse.error object.type={}", 
                   o.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            throw new JsonProcessingEx();
        }
    };
}
```

This way, your code compiles without needing a type witness:

```
MLAdhocResponseVO response = JsonUtils.jsonDeSerializer(MLAdhocResponseVO.class)
    .apply("{}");
```

And even this standalone expression is correctly typed:

```
JsonUtils.jsonDeSerializer(MLAdhocResponseVO.class)
        .apply("{}");
```

Comment: My bad, how can I missed initial typecasting :(, however last approach seems to be pretty clean and best to solve this scenario from much cleaner and usable API perspective.